# strange behavior of this keywork in JS

Tags: javascript

I have some code, which is really simple, but if I use this keyword, it won't work. I already searched internet, but this keyword is still a mystery.

Anyone can explain to me why?

```
let backdrop = document.querySelector('.backdrop');
let modal = document.querySelector('.modal')
let selectPlanButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.plan button');
let modalBoBtn = document.querySelector('.modal__action--negative');
let toggleBtn = document.querySelector('.toggle-button');
let mobileNav = document.querySelector('.mobile-nav');

for(let i=0; i<selectPlanButtons.length; i++){
    selectPlanButtons[i].addEventListener('click', showModal);    
}

backdrop.addEventListener('click', closeBackdrop);
modalBoBtn.addEventListener('click', closeModal);
toggleBtn.addEventListener('click', closeShowToggleBtn);

function closeBackdrop(){
    mobileNav.style.display = 'none';
    closeModal(); // if change to this.closeModal(); => won't work
}

function closeShowToggleBtn(){
    mobileNav.style.display = 'block';
    backdrop.style.display = 'block';
}

function showModal(){
    modal.style.display = 'block';
    backdrop.style.display = 'block';
};

function closeModal(){
    modal.style.display = 'none';
    backdrop.style.display = 'none';
};
```

Comment: Why do you expect `this.closeModal()` to work? Why do you *want* it to work?

Comment: So why if I use `this.closeModal()`, it won't work? I assume that in this context, `this.closeModal()` refer to closeModal function, but actually it's not. So which `closeModal` which `this.closeModal()` refer to?

Comment: You did not answer my question: why do you think that it **should** work?

Answer (score 0):

The catch here is that in JavaScript for a regular `function` `this` refers to its execution context. When you register `backdrop.addEventListener('click', closeBackdrop);` `closeBackdrop()` will be called in the context of an HTML element, I'm guessing `HTMLButtonElement` in this case. Because of that, inside `closeBackdrop()` `this` refers to the HTML element that handles the `click` event. `showModal()` is defined in the global context and so it is `undefined` on this HTML element where `closeBackdrop()` is being called. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) you can find a more complete explanation on how this works.